# Javascript and HTML5: Object opacity and color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to figure out how to make the 1st square opaque when i hover over it with the mouse and less opaque when i stop hovering over it. with the second square i'm trying to figure out how to change the color from red to blue when i hover over and move the mouse away. I got everything else done that I need to get done I'm just having issues with the opacity and the color, if i could get some help on this it would greatly be appreciated

```js
// The sprite object
var spriteObject =
{
    sourceX: 0,
    sourceY: 0,
    sourceWidth: 64,
    sourceHeight: 64,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 64,
    height: 64,
    
    left: function()
    {
        return this.x;
    },
    
    right: function()
    {
        return this.x + this.width;
    },
    
    top: function()
    {
        return this.y;
    },
    
    bottom: function()
    {
        return this.y + this.height;
    }
};

//--Main program
//The canvas and its drawing surface
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var drawingSurface = canvas.getContext("2d");

var square = Object.create(spriteObject);
square.x = canvas.width / 2 - square.width / 2;
square.y = canvas.height / 2 - square.height / 2;

var square2 = Object.create(spriteObject);
square2.x = canvas.width / 4 - square.width / 4;
square2.y = canvas.height / 4 - square.height / 4;

var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
image.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/512";
// image.src = "squares.png";

//Canvas text properties
drawingSurface.font = "normal bold 18px Hevetica";
drawingSurface.fillStyle = "black";
drawingSurface.textBaseline = "top";

//The collision message
var message = "No collision...";

//Variables to store the mouse's x and y positions
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

//Add a mousemove event listener
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveHandler, false);

function mousemoveHandler(event)
{
    //Find the mosue's x and y position on the canvas
    mouseX = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
}

function loadHandler()
{
    update();
}

function update()
{
    // The animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(update, canvas);
    
    if(hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, square))
    {
        message = "Collision!";
    }
    else
    {
        message = "No collision...";
    }
    
    render();
}

function hitTestPoint (pointX, pointY, sprite)
{
    var hit =   pointX > sprite.left() &&
                pointX < sprite.right() &&
                pointY > sprite.top() &&
                pointY < sprite.bottom();
                
    return hit;
                
}

function render()
{
    drawingSurface.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    drawingSurface.drawImage(
        image,
        square.sourceX,
        square.sourceY,
        square.sourceWidth,
        square.sourceHeight,
        
        square.x,
        square.y,
        square.width,
        square.height);
        
    //Dispaly the text message above the square
    drawingSurface.fillText(message, square.x, square.y - 45);
    
        drawingSurface.drawImage(
        image,
        square2.sourceX,
        square2.sourceY,
        square2.sourceWidth,
        square2.sourceHeight,
        
        square2.x,
        square2.y,
        square2.width,
        square2.height);
        
    //Dispaly the text message above the square
    drawingSurface.fillText(message, square2.x, square2.y - 45);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="550" height="400" style="border: 1px dashed black"></canvas>
```

Comment: Welcome! Please may you remove all the extra code which doesn’t show the issue? The code should be a [mcve], emphasis on minimal. This will help others help you.

Comment: of course I can remove it

Comment: Why would you remove my edit that provides an excutable example for you :/

Comment: @HaoWu the OP might have been already editing when you were? May you try again?

Comment: I'm rolling it back if OP is fine with it...

Answer (score 1):

use 'globalAlpha'.

```js
// The sprite object
var spriteObject =
{
    sourceX: 0,
    sourceY: 0,
    sourceWidth: 64,
    sourceHeight: 64,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 64,
    height: 64,
    
    left: function()
    {
        return this.x;
    },
    
    right: function()
    {
        return this.x + this.width;
    },
    
    top: function()
    {
        return this.y;
    },
    
    bottom: function()
    {
        return this.y + this.height;
    }
};

//--Main program
//The canvas and its drawing surface
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var drawingSurface = canvas.getContext("2d");

var square = Object.create(spriteObject);
square.x = canvas.width / 2 - square.width / 2;
square.y = canvas.height / 2 - square.height / 2;

var square2 = Object.create(spriteObject);
square2.x = canvas.width / 4 - square.width / 4;
square2.y = canvas.height / 4 - square.height / 4;

var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
image.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/512";
// image.src = "squares.png";

//Canvas text properties
drawingSurface.font = "normal bold 18px Hevetica";
drawingSurface.fillStyle = "black";
drawingSurface.textBaseline = "top";

//The collision message
// var message = "No collision...";

var hitState = 0

//Variables to store the mouse's x and y positions
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

//Add a mousemove event listener
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveHandler, false);

function mousemoveHandler(event)
{
    //Find the mosue's x and y position on the canvas
    mouseX = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
}

function loadHandler()
{
    update();
}

function update()
{
    // The animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(update, canvas);
    
    if(hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, square))
    {
        hitState = 1;
        // message = "Collision!";
    }
    else if(hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, square2))
    {
        hitState = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        hitState = 0;
        // message = "No collision...";
    }
    
    render();
}

function hitTestPoint (pointX, pointY, sprite)
{
    var hit =   pointX > sprite.left() &&
                pointX < sprite.right() &&
                pointY > sprite.top() &&
                pointY < sprite.bottom();
                
    return hit;
                
}

function render()
{
    drawingSurface.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if (hitState === 1)
    {
        drawingSurface.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    }
    drawingSurface.drawImage(
        image,
        square.sourceX,
        square.sourceY,
        square.sourceWidth,
        square.sourceHeight,
        
        square.x,
        square.y,
        square.width,
        square.height);
    drawingSurface.globalAlpha = 1;
        
    //Dispaly the text message above the square
    drawingSurface.fillText(hitState === 1 ? "Collision!" : "No collision...", square.x, square.y - 45);
    
    if (hitState === 2)
    {
        drawingSurface.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    }
    drawingSurface.drawImage(
        image,
        square2.sourceX,
        square2.sourceY,
        square2.sourceWidth,
        square2.sourceHeight,
        
        square2.x,
        square2.y,
        square2.width,
        square2.height);
    drawingSurface.globalAlpha = 1;
        
    //Dispaly the text message above the square
    drawingSurface.fillText(hitState === 2 ? "Collision!" : "No collision...", square2.x, square2.y - 45);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="550" height="400" style="border: 1px dashed black"></canvas>
```

Comment: What did you change/fix?

Comment: @evolutionxbox When the mouse hovers over the square,  its transparency is adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one the e parameter has an x and y property for mouse position and here's and if statement that should work

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove)

function mouseMove(){
    if(e.x >= x position of object && e.<= x positon of object + width of object){
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)"
    }
}
```

Comment: where exactly would I put this in my code?